# Ускорить обработку списка в Python

Tags: python

У меня есть задача по обработке большого списка, ниже приведу идею работы моей программы.
Кто может подсказать, каким инструментом ускорить работу?

```
main_list = [a_0, a_1, a_2, .... a_n]     # Это список, который содержит в себе около 8000 переменных float
main_list.append(a_new)                   # Добавляю новую переменную в список, добавление идет циклом
my_funct(min(main_list), max(main_list))  # Отправляю максимальное и минимальное значение в другию функцию
del (main_list[0])                        # Удаляю 0-й элемент из списка
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте, что вам именно надо? Быстро отсортировать список от повторов, или же обход по каждой ячейке массива циклом?

Comment: вы уже делали "profiling"? Если да, то в каком месте максимальные "тормоза"??

Comment: В текущей формулировке - это мне напоминает лечение по телефону. Можете понятно объяснить что вы пытаетесь сделать и привести соответствующие куски кода и желательно небольшой пример входных данных и результат, который вы хотите получить?

Comment: список из 8000 элементов - это __очень__ мало. Если бы была понятная формулировка задачи, вам бы уже давно привели максимально эффективное и быстрое решение ;) PS в зависимости от задачи можно использовать `numpy`, `numba`, `numexpr` - все они очень быстро работают с массивами и матрицами.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Так это всё в цикле происходит или один раз? Если в цикле, то где начинается и где заканчивается этот цикл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый раз список из 8000 элементов дважды анализируется - один раз для поиска максимума, второй раз для поиска минимума. При добавлении следующего элемента имеющиеся 8000 анализируются заново, хотя ничего нового там нет. Достаточно каждый новый элемент сравнивать с известными максимумом и минимумом и тем самым избежать 16000 сравнений. Примерно так

```
main_list = [a_0, a_1, a_2, .... a_n] # Это список, который содержит в себе около 8000 переменных float
minimum = min(main_list)
maximum = max(main_list)
main_list.append(a_new)  # Добавляю новую переменную в список, добавление идет циклом
if a_new > maximum:
    maximum = a_new
if a_new < minimum:
    minimum = a_new
my_funct(minimum, maximum)  # Отправляю максимальное и минимальное значение в другию функцию
del (main_list[0])
```

Да и вместо удаления первого элемента возможно дешевле брать срез

```
main_list = main_list[1:]
```

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, попробую сравнить скорости вычислений

Comment: Как вы считаете: обоснованно будет применять NumPy для этой задачи?

Comment: Спасибо за совет, это значительно увеличило скорость работы программы

Answer (score 1):

1. определение `min`, `max` при последовательном добавлении элементов в список для каждого добавления **должно исключать** просмотр элементов списка

например так:

```
min_value, max_value = min(main_list), max(main_list)

while True:
    main_list.append(a_new)
    min_value = min(a_new, min_value)
    max_value = max(a_new, max_value)
```

2. удаление 0-го элемента - тут надо смотреть как вообще в питоне устроен список (например в c++ для такой цели вместо `vector` лучше использовать `list`)

в питоне наверное быстрее среза ничего нет (но не уверен)

```
main_list = main_list[1:]
```

Comment: Если `del main_list[0]` должно происходить после каждой итерации то это не поможет

Comment: @Борис Верховский, если список фиксированного размера (т.е. программа не работает сутки и не генерирует миллиарды записей), то можно ничего не удалять, а просто двигать `pos` по списку, список конечно будет расти с добавлением элементов, но опять же если это не выжирает критические объемы памяти, то можно вообще не удалять элементы, а просто двигаться по списке (т.е. указывать где он фактически начинается)

Comment: Я о том что если первый элемент являлся минимумом а его надо удалять при каждой итерации, то `min_value = min(a_new, min_value)` даст не тот результат

Comment: @Борис Верховский, понял, но это не проблема - надо кроме `min_value` держать еще и `min_index` и если он равен 0, то уже рассчитать `min_value` по всему списку, если значения в списке не расположены строго по убыванию, то это в любом случае будет эффективнее, чем каждый раз по всему списку лазить